# Using foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails newbie, have a simple question:
I have two tables, valor, belongs to an object at the variables table

On the page of a single variable, I put the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Novo Valor', :controller => "valors", :action=> 'new', :id=>@variable%>
```

So the URL appears as: http://localhost:3000/valors/new?id=1

But how do I use the id value represented at the URL in order to create a new valor object with the foreign key variable_id=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
# Your action
def new
  @valor = Valor.new(:variable_id => params[:id])
end

# Then in the view:
<%= form_for(@valor) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You could also simplify the action and make it more flexible by passing the full object parameters in the same way `create` and `update` works, like:

```
def new
  @valor = Valor.new(params[:valor] || {})
end

# making your link:
<%= link_to 'Novo Valor', :controller => "valors", :action=> 'new', :valor => { :variable_id => @variable } %>
```

This makes the generated URL a bit uglier, but would allow you to pass arbitrary creation parameters to the new record, rather than manually building them in the controller.

---

Side note, given that you're using standard resourceful routes, you could simplify the link generation by using the named route for a new `Valor`:

```
<%= link_to 'Novo valor', new_valor_path(:valor => { :variable_id => @variable }) %>
```

Comment: didn't work, what i need is a way to access that variable_id on the new valor page, but when i call @variable or similar in the new valor page it returns nil value

Comment: You're passing `@variable` to the new page as `id`, making it available in the new action as `params[:id]`.  I simply used that to build the new `Valor` object.  If you want to store it as `@variable` again in the new action, `@variable = params[:id]` would do that.

Comment: thanks for the params[:id] reference, that was enough to get the variable id on the new valor page, but I am still unable to create a new object with that reference, i can't quite understand why

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue, now my problem is I get the following error message:

undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

that happens when after selecting the variable and value for valor clas

Answer (score 1):

As numbers1311407 said, store id or the entire object in an instance variable `@variable = params[:id]` or `@variable = whatever.you.like` in the controller. And then you can access this variable anytime:

```
valor = Valor.new
valor.variable = @variable
valor.save
```

> Something extra: You could use Inflections.rb to handle (valor ->
>   valores) instead of (valor -> valors)